# Is this (isset() && !empty()) function redundant?

Tags: php, function

```
<?php
function isset_n_empty($var) {
    if (isset($var) && !empty($var)){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
echo isset_n_empty($x ?? null);

?>
```

my function is supposed to do the simple `if (isset() && !empty())` logic and i used `$x ?? null` because if it is not used it would give me this error for undefined variables as the example

```
E_NOTICE : type 8 -- Undefined variable: x -- at line z
```

is it redundant or well-optimized?

Comment: Pass a reference  `isset_n_empty(&$var)` to avoid notice

Comment: Also you can write it shortly like `return isset($var) && !empty($var);`

Comment: @Yang How does `&$` affects the function becasue i can't find an explaination about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A variable that isn't set is considered empty by `empty()`.

Therefore, if the variable is not set, it is also empty.

Your code could be shortened by using:

```
echo !empty($x);
```

I suppose that makes the answer to your question `yes`.

Comment: your example would not yield the same result - which is to tell if a variable both set and falsey.

Comment: That would be the case if the question was about `isset($x) && empty($x)`.

Comment: `!empty($x)` tells you that x is set and not empty which is not that same as *set and empty*.

Answer (score 0):

yes, the isset is redundant. if it's !empty(), then isset() always returns true.

Answer (score 0):

No the function is not redundant.  It tells you if your variable is set but also falsey.  There's nothing wrong with it.

On the other hand it seems like something that shouldn't really require a function of it's own.  Instead of:

```
echo isset_n_empty($x ?? null);
```

You can just do:

```
echo isset($x) && !$x;
```

It's less code and doesn't require a function.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help:

```
function isset_not_empty($var){
    if(!isset($var))
        return false;
    else
         return (!empty($var))

 }
```